# Schematic link between Python, C, Theano, CUDA, Windows 7, Machine Code, CPU, GPU and many more?

Tags: python, gpgpu, theano, deep-learning

I do not have a thorough computer science background and I am trying to find my way trough deep learning. I was at the point that I wanted to make a decision on which framework I want to use to start coding some networks. Nevertheless, going through many discussions on fora and other websites raised another question that kept me busy for two days and which seems to be answered nowhere.

At this point I still can't get a complete understanding on how my Theano code in Python is finally executed on the CPU and GPU (is this "machine code"?).

As an answer I imagine a schematic view (of course can be in words) on the link between how all the parts play together in a Theano program, mainly:

- my code
- Theano
- Python interpreter
- C
- NVCC
- CPU
- GPU
- CUDA

Also I'd like to understand the role of Python bytecode in the context of Theano, and how it differs from the code (machine code?) that is acutally executed on the CPU or the GPU.

If it helps, I am working on a Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Voted to close. These are too many (basic) questions mashed into one. What is machine code? What is byte code? How is c code compiled into what? How is python code compiled into what? What is mingw, what is cuda? What is the difference between GPU and CPU?

Comment: This is a very good question and indeed one that deserves a proper answer. Here's [my first approach to it](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/d9fb7735cdb7d61caaf1) I hope the question will be re-opened.

Comment: @Framester obviously the OP is not so much interested in a detailed explanation of all these terms but more so wants to understand just how lo and behold a few expressions in Python unleash a powerful program that involves advanced concepts like GPU, and what is byte code v.s. machine code anyway? The question is broad not because the OP wants to have all these terms explained in nitty-gritty details, but because he made a deliberate effort to understand it all, finding a lot of seemingly gobbledygook. Let the SO community play its role and break it down for him in understandable parts.

Comment: @miraculixx thank you for your nice explanation. This was already really helpful and certainly the way to go.

Comment: @Framester I do not agree with your response. The point is that I want a simple scheme and as such no detailed description of everything involved. I am convinced that many people would be able to answer the separate points very well in a detailed manner, even me at this point, but nevertheless I have difficulties in placing this in the bigger perspective with perfect links in between everything involved.